# Significado de "cita telúrica"

Tags: significado

En "Los mares del Sur", de Manuel Vázquez Montalbán:

> Y otras veces, cuando se enamoraba de alguien concreto, de pronto
>   tenía la sensación de que le estaba esperando en un punto exacto de la
>   ciudad, generalmente en el puerto, y acudía allí con el reloj
>   impaciente, convencido de que se cumpliría la cita telúrica.

Pero según la rae, telúrico:

```
1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la Tierra como planeta.
2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al telurismo.
```

Y telurismo:

```
1. m. Influencia del suelo de una comarca sobre sus habitantes.
```

¿Qué significado tiene aquí telúrico?

Answer (score 5):

Me da la impresión que la RAE nos da una definición demasiado estrecha, pues la raiz latina Tellus viene a significar tanto [la deidad de la Madre Tierra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_%28mythology%29) (y de ahí cabe generalizar al planeta tierra) como el nombre común 'suelo' o territorio (ver enlace anterior), al que hace referencia la segunda definición. Es este origen divino de Tellus el que nos permite utilizar el adjetivo telúrico como relativo a la tierra como entidad capaz de interactuar con las personas.

Mi impresión es que el autor utiliza el término '*cita telúrica*', quizá con cierta dosis de licencia poética, para dar a entender que la cita es más con el lugar que con la otra persona, que, según leemos, no necesariamente va a acudir.

Comment: Entiendo qué es como una "cita terrenal" algo que es de humanos, terrenal, relativo a la tierra. Digo, ya estamos entrando en interpretaciones.

Comment: al parecer segun google en España es donde mas se usa esa palabra `telúrica`

Comment: Yo diría que va más por el lado de instintivo, de fuerza de la naturaleza.

Comment: O bien como algo que la madre Tierra provoca. En cualquier caso, estoy de acuerdo en que es una licencia poética que, como dice @EmilioGort, se usa en España con cierta frecuencia. Aunque a mí, personalmente, me parece un uso horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya se contestó en el Centro Virtual Cervantes, en el Foro del Español (pregunta 187291 de Luis Lop):

> .187291. De una novela de Vázquez Montalbán: «Cita telúrica»
>
> La dirección de este mensaje es:
>   «http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer1.asp?vId=187291».
>
> Título: De una novela de Vázquez Montalbán: «Cita telúrica»
>
> Autor: Luis Lop
>
> Fecha y hora: lunes, 30 de junio de 2014, 13:01 h
>
> De "Los mares del Sur", de Manuel Vázquez Montalbán:
>
> "Y otras veces, cuando se enamoraba de alguien concreto, de pronto
>   tenía la sensación de que le estaba esperando en un punto exacto de la
>   ciudad, generalmente en el puerto, y acudía allí con el reloj
>   impaciente, convencido de que se cumpliría la cita telúrica."
>
> Pero según la rae, telúrico:
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la Tierra como planeta.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al telurismo.
>
> Y telurismo:
>
> 1. m. Influencia del suelo de una comarca sobre sus habitantes.
>
> ¿Qué significado tiene aquí telúrico?

"telúrico" significa "inexorable". *cf*. respuestas de Noel Torres e Ignacio Frías:

> .187300. Re: De una novela de Vázquez Montalbán: «Cita telúrica»
>
> La dirección de este mensaje es:
>   «http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer1.asp?vId=187300».
>
> Título: Telúrico
>
> Autor: Noel Torres
>
> Fecha y hora: lunes, 30 de junio de 2014, 16:24 h
>
> En ocasiones, el adjetivo 'telúrico', sobre todo en literatura, se
>   utiliza para dar a entender que algo tiene la fuerza o la
>   inevitabilidad "movimientos telúricos". Así, una cita telúrica sería
>   una cita tan inevitable como el movimiento de los continentes.

--

> .187314.
>
> Re: De una novela de Vázquez Montalbán: «Cita telúrica»
>
> La dirección de este mensaje es:
>   «http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer1.asp?vId=187314».
>
> Título: Buenos días, Noel
>
> Autor: Ignacio Frías
>
> Fecha y hora: martes, 01 de julio de 2014, 10:03 h
>
> inexorable.
>
> Que no se puede evitar.
>
> Saludos Ignacio

Comment: Esto que pones es simplemente la opinión de una persona en otro foro. No niego que telúrico pueda significar inexorable, pero esto necesita un cierto soporte, por ejemplo otro diccionario que recoja esta acepción o simplemente dando alguna cita de otros escritores reconocidos.

Comment: @deStrangis de hecho, si te fijas, la pregunta es exactamente la misma y con la misma redacción (y el nombre del preguntante es muy similar). Puedes echar un vistazo extra en http://dirae.es/palabras/tel%C3%BArico donde "sentimiento telúrico" es el cuarto compuesto más utilizado de la palabra. Vamos, que a esta persona ya se le había contestado correctamente y vino aquí a buscar una segunda opinión (lo cual es perfectamente loable), pero la realidad es tozuda y la respuesta es la que es.